# Is it forbidden to buy bad merchandise in order to get a refund?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, gezel-stealing, emes-truth-honesty

**The background:**
I bought neodymium magnets from China off of ebay.

The magnets were NOT neodymium and the item was not as good as I expected.

This is a common Chinese practice on ebay. The Chinese government sponsors the postage and the seller sells junk to US. They do not have to pay American postage on the outbound delivery because of the Universal Postal Union Treaty.

For most Americans, the hassle of returning the item is not worth it so the seller keeps the money and the item doesn't cost them much to produce.

If you do complain, the seller will offer to let you keep the item and they refund half the money, which is still a healthy profit for them.

If you are more forceful and threaten to give them a bad rating, they will usually let you keep the item and refund you, because their expense was only a couple of dimes. The risk that eBay will come down hard on them (forcing them to pay American postage rates on the return) is too high.

I was able to successfully negotiate that I keep four of these with a full refund.

I know that, in the future, eBay will take my side if the seller passes these off to me as neodymium.

**The question:**
Can I, knowing the magnets are not as advertised, order 1000 of these, make a stink that they are not neodymium, wrestle my money back, and sell them myself (with an accurate description)?

Comment: Let's see if I can summarize your question. You want to knowingly commit fraud on a large scale, both against the seller and eBay, and against your customers, and you want to know if that's ok?

Comment: There's no fraud against my customers. eBay is neither losing nor gaining money. The only party who loses money is the dishonest seller. If you think it is forbidden, please answer why it is forbidden? Furthermore, the seller has the ability to do teshuva and take his listing down after he has already been warned (by me) that he is not selling neodymium.

Comment: As a practical matter, I doubt you can assume that the vendor's willingness to refund scales up to that volume. But the core of the question is interesting from an ethical and halachic perspective.

Comment: I suggest the title should be "May I extort a merchant who compromised themselves?", and the answer is "no."

Comment: Interestingly chazzal spoke about not stealing in order to pay kefel. They never(?) spoke about not leaving your items to be stolen in order to collect kefel.

Comment: If you order 1000 of these, then it will be worth their while to pay for the return postage, which will leave you with zero at the end of the day.

Comment: Not if I buy them in four unit increments!

Comment: You probably will get flagged by ebay or the seller, for being the guy who makes these small increment purchases, and then challenges the charges.

Comment: And what are you going to sell it as, regular magnets?

Comment: Could this question be rephrased as, "Can you steal from a thief?"

Comment: Im not stealing. I would be happy to return the misdescribed items if the merchant pays return shipping. The merchant chooses not to send a shipping label.